# How to Access RDS Proxy from a Different AWS Region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I have a RDS database and a RDS proxy in one region.

However, I also have a lambda function in a different region that need to connect to the RDS proxy in the first region.

I know that the RDS proxy can't be publicly accessible and need to be within the same VPC as the instance trying to connect to it.

Is there a way to allow a lambda function to connect to a RDS proxy in a different region?

I know that an RDS DB can be publicly accessible, however I was getting sql timeout errors in my lambda functions, which is why I chose to use a RDS proxy.

Comment: Have you tried this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/#:~:text=Sign%20into%20the%20AWS%20Lambda,and%20choose%20Add%20Database%20Proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that the RDS proxy can't be publicly accessible and need to be
> **within the same VPC as the instance trying to connect to it**.

I think the part in bold is partially incorrect. The RDS proxy has to be in the same VPC as the RDS database. As far as I can tell, the instance trying to connect doesn't need to be in the same VPC, I think it could also be in a peered VPC.

To answer your question, I would suggest placing the Lambda function in a VPC in the other region, and create a [VPC peering connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) between the two VPCs.